# What are the conditions (and implications) of entering an ostensible contract without capacity to do so?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales, consent, capacity, intoxication

A recent discussion touches in capacity to consent to forming contracts:

> @gaazkam my answer
> outlines the four required
> elements a person must be
> able to understand in order
> to have the capacity to
> consent to sexual
> touching. This is a specific
> test in the context of
> sexual touching. Certainly
> it is possible, perhaps even
> likely, that a person who
> lacks the capacity to
> consent to sexual touching
> would also lack the
> capacity to enter into a
> contract, but this is not at
> alla necessary implication.
> And my answer also
> clarifies that incapacity is
> not merely because a
> person "is drunk". — Jen
>
> [@Jen] Interesting. While this is a
> digression, might | ask
> about some comments
> from Reddit? They said
> that if Josie lacks
> capability to consent
> because she's drunk, then
> by the same token she
> cannot call Uber to drive
> her home. She's drunk, so
> she cannot consent to the
> transaction of driving her
> home in exchange for her
> money, so the Uber driver
> commits theft against her.
> Does this attempt at
> reductio ad absurdum hold
> any water? Or does the law
> let Josie call Uber while
> prohibiting her from
> consenting to sex? — `gaazkam`

Bob is extremely intoxicated and delirious, and stumbles into a convenience store and buys a candy bar. Whether he has then subsequently eaten the candy bar or not, is there an argument that the contract was void?

What if there was more involved and extensive coaxing involved? For example, suppose that Al walks into a strip club in a similarly delirious state of intoxication but some of the strippers approach him and actively take advantage of his intoxicated state to entice him to additional services, perhaps even intentionally specifically targeting him for more aggressive selling than others due to noticing his vulnerable and intoxicated state. Something tells me that this would only tip the position in a criminal context by increasing the defendant stripper’s culpability but it would matter much less in a civil context where the questions involved are generally less of culpability and usually more about (generally strict-er) *liability*, thus suggesting that the questions that are important are more simply of the validity of the contract based simply on both parties’ capacities to form it/consent than about the degree of active exploitation or enticement by one party of another.

Answer (score 1):

### The contract *may* be [voidable](https://www.australiancontractlaw.info/law/capacity)

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The criteria is:

- One party must have been unable to understand the nature of the contract being made. Note, not that they *didn’t* understand, but that they *couldn’t* understand even if the contract had been explained to them [Gibbons v Wright (1954) 91 CLR 423](https://www.australiancontractlaw.info/cases/database/gibbons-v-wright);
- The other party knew or should have known this [Blomley v Ryan (1956) 99 CLR 362](https://www.australiancontractlaw.info/cases/database/blomley-v-ryan).

The onus of proving both elements rests with the party trying to void the contract.

It is not necessary that the other party took advantage of the intoxication but, if they did, that might be evidence that the first party could not understand.

However, courts are reluctant to void contracts where one party claims self-induced intoxication because of the obvious moral hazard this involves. That’s not saying they won’t, but Blomley v Ryan shows just how far this has to go.

Further, where the goods and services have been consumed, providing the non-intoxicated party has “clean hands” they will be entitled to payment under the equitable doctrines of quantum meruit or unjust enrichment. For retail goods and services where the general public pays an advertised and generally non-negotiable price, the amount payable will likely be the same as under contract.

In addition, statutes in most jurisdictions have closed off the argument of incapacity in contracts for necessities - which would include candy bars and, possibly, whatever “additional services” a stripper might offer.

Notwithstanding, neither of these contracts are going to result in litigation due to the insignificant sums at stake. It is worth noting that most cases of this kind are for sales of land or similar valuable and durable things.

Comment: What’s the definition of necessities?

Comment: @TylerDurden things that are necessary for maintaining your lifestyle

Comment: Not many would agree with your definition of "necessities"...

Comment: @MichaelHall not my definition - the one that courts use.